# What happens in Bash after calling exit?

Tags: bash

I understand that when I call exit, it is an alias for logout. Sometimes, just for fun, when I need to remove myself from a session I will type `exit && 1`. Now what happens after the `exit` has been executed. Where does the `1` go? Typing 1 into bash yields (obviously) this: `1: command not found`. I'm not asking why 1 doesn't work. I'm asking where does the 1 go after calling exit? 1 is just an example, replace it with any other command.

But typing `exit &&&&&&& 1` yields a syntax error. So the right hand must be evaluated.

**Disclaimer** : This is a question in which interests me. There is not particular reason for this question besides the fact that I am curious about what happens.

Comment: I don't think it's ever evaluated.

Comment: You can read it yourself: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exit.def

Comment: Can you show me in the source code of `Bash` where exactly it is not evaluated?

Comment: @dawud I post that comment before I saw yours. ha

Comment: **`exit` is *not* an alias for `logout`**

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for clearing that up. Any other input on the question would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't really affect your question, but while exiting a *login* shell will log you out, shells in a GUI context (e.g.) aren't usually login shells. `exit` just terminates the shell process.

Comment: "So the right hand must be evaluated" -- The right hand side gets parsed, not evaluated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you type `exit`, the shell will quit immediately, `1` is not evaluated. If you check the source code for [exit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exit.def), you can see:

```
int
exit_builtin (list)
     WORD_LIST *list;
{
  if (interactive)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, login_shell ? _("logout\n") : "exit\n");
      fflush (stderr);
    }

  return (exit_or_logout (list));
}
```

The last thing `exit` does: `return (exit_or_logout (list))`

```
static int
exit_or_logout (list)
     WORD_LIST *list;
{
  int exit_value;

  ..............

  /* Get return value if present.  This means that you can type
     `logout 5' to a shell, and it returns 5. */

  /* If we're running the exit trap (running_trap == 1, since running_trap
     gets set to SIG+1), and we don't have a argument given to `exit'
     (list == 0), use the exit status we saved before running the trap
     commands (trap_saved_exit_value). */
  exit_value = (running_trap == 1 && list == 0) ? trap_saved_exit_value : get_exitstat (list);

  bash_logout ();

  last_command_exit_value = exit_value;

  /* Exit the program. */
  jump_to_top_level (EXITPROG);
  /*NOTREACHED*/
}
```

The syntax error in `exit &&&&&&& 1` due to parsing error, not the result of evaluating expression. Parsing occurs before any command run.

Comment: @mikeserv You are confused. The arguments to `exit` are indeed evaluated, but any (separate) commands which come *after* it are not. `exit 5` is a single command; `exit 5 && exit 10` is two, and the second will never be executed.

Answer (score 5):

It's never executed, because the shell exited. Here is an easy way to test:

```
$ bash
$ touch /tmp/testfile
$ exit && rm /tmp/testfile
exit
$ ls /tmp/testfile 
/tmp/testfile
```

Note that I first started a second shell so that my XTerm wouldn't exit. The same result is obtained when I don't do so and check for file existence from a different window.

`cmd1 && cmd2` means run `cmd1` then, if it's successful (exit code = 0), run `cmd2`. So, first the shell runs `exit`. Exiting causes the shell to cease existing, so it never gets to the "if it's successful" part.

Your followup with the syntax error is different: Syntax is checked when the input line is *parsed*, before any part of it is executed. Basically, bash doesn't understand what you mean at all, so it can't begin to execute it.

Comment: Just for some fun: `function exit() { echo "where is your god now?"; }; exit && echo eeek`

Comment: @Patrick But Control-D still works! You haven't obtained everlasting shell-life yet.

Comment: `kill -9 $$` works too, although terminal emulator will complain that the shell crashed (at least Yakuake does).